# Customize value after copying the cell value in vba macros

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I want to copy a multiple cells in a row and paste it in a customized format.

For example:

> Sheet1 --> value in cell(A1) = 10
>              value in cell(B1) = 20
>              value in cell(c1) = 30

Now copy the value of these cells and paste in a desired format like,
Cell(D1) value should be like this ->

> f(10),b(20),x(30),total = 60

If not possible with copy/paste method is there any other method?

Thanks.

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: Range("A1:C1").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("D1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Comment: Above is the only code format i know to copy and paste but dont have an idea to format it.

Comment: to put things in the format of code you put 4 spaces at the start of the line

Comment: `Range("A1:A2").Select
Selection.Copy

Range("C3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste`

Comment: ok so you have code - i am trying to work out what your second quote is about tho

Comment: I have the the simple code but i want to know is it possible to format copied value in desired format

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("D1") = "f(" & .Range("A1") & "),b(" & .Range("B1") & "),x(" & .Range("C1") & "),total = " & WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range("A1:C1"))
End With
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response @user3598756. i will try it.

Comment: @Zanxzan: did you get through it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to pass in a range of values and a target range for the output.

```
Sub CreateSummary()

Dim x() As Variant
Dim y As Range

    x = Range("A1:C1")
    Set y = Range("D1")

    y = "f(" & x(1, 1) & "),b(" & x(1, 2) & "),x(" & _
     x(1, 3) & "),total = " & WorksheetFunction.Sum(x)

End Sub
```

The result based on your example:

[image: screenshot of worked example]

Comment: Thank you so much @ Robert Mearns